# Vector transpose in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I couldn't find the definition or lemma for transposing a vector of type `(real,'n) vec` in `Finite_Cartesian_Product` theory. I'm trying to substitute a transposed vector by a transpose matrix and a vector, for instance, if the vector `e = A x` then the transpose of `e`(`e^T`) leads to transposing `A` and `x` (`e^T = A^T x^T`). Can I do this in Isabelle/HOL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, unless my linear algebra is completely failing me right now, `(AB)^T = B^T A^T`, not `A^T B^T`, so your second equation should be `e^T = x^T A^T`

To answer your actual question: I suggest you have a look at the constants `rowvector`, `columnvector`, and `transpose` from `~~/src/HOL/Analysis/Cartesian_Euclidean_Space`. The first two allow you to transform a vector of length `n` into a `1 × n` (resp. `n × 1`) matrix and the latter allows you to transpose a matrix.

I guess your `e = A x` would look like `columnvector e = A ** columnvector x` and your `e^T = x^T A^T` would be `rowvector e = rowvector x ** transpose A`.